# When testing smart contracts with Ethers js and hardhat, how do I create a provider to the hardhat mainnet fork?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I can create a provider fairly easily to Rinkeby, Ropsten and the other testnets but I can't seem to figure out how to create a provider that connects to a hardhat mainnet fork.

Answer (score 1):

In hardhat, I suppose you must have enabled mainnet forking already

```
hardhat: {
  forking: {
    url: ''https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/key',
      blockNumber: 13413700,
    },
}
```

Then, you can get the ethers provider by using `hre.ethers.provider` in your code.